# Need a sed command to replace double quotes within a string

Tags: sed

I have a string, "[""Jonathan"", ""Eric""]", ""Hilda"". I need to replace all the double quotes within the square bracket with nothing using sed, so that the output looks like "[Jonathan, Eric]", ""Hilda"".

Comment: Please format your sample input/output and add your attempts. Also, is `perl` okay?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '["Jonathan", "Eric"]', '""Hilda""' |
sed -E ':a; s/(\[[^]"]*)"/\1/; ta'
```

This command works as follows:

`:a` defines a label 'a'.

`s/(\[[^]"]*)"/\1/` is the substitution command. It matches a square bracket followed by any characters that are not a closing square bracket or a quote followed by a quote. It then replaces this with the capture group (everything except the quote). The -E option is used to enable extended regular expressions, which allows the use of parentheses for grouping without needing to escape them.

`ta` branches (jumps) to label 'a' if the last `s///` command made a substitution. This command will keep removing the double quotes within the brackets until there are none left.

Help doc: https://quickref.me/sed.html

Comment: By adding the `-z` option this solution will also work where the `[` and `]` are split over one or more lines.